# Aggregating capacity for multiple teams in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have a project with multiple teams managed in TFS 2013 update 2.

The problem is that if i have two teams, and a person works 5 hours in each, when i look at the teams parent, i dont see the value automatically updated to 10.

In other words if i make a mistake and define a capacity that sums up to more than the actual work day, there is no way for me to see it.

I can develop a server extension that will update the capacity of the parent team, but i am stil hoping for an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no solution. Team Capacity is not easily queryable, the UI has no option to do it and it's not part of the Data Warehouse.

TFS kind of assumes that a team member is part of one team. And one team only. And have work flow to the team, instead of people swicthing between teams. [I suggest you file a suggestion on Uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).