# Why capacity of same users not mirrored among teams in TFS

Tags: tfs

I tried to configure my TFS (2013) project.
Its my first sprint and we have 2 teams.

- Team Father

  - Team A
  - Team B

And i want to set capacity of developers in team a and to see it in the team father.

So i had set the capacity of the members in team a, after that i get into the team father area and looked at the capacity and the members that i have set for them the capacity wasn't set.

So why TFS let me set different capacity for same members in a one point of time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hierarchy of teams for capacity and other settings. Each team is independent, so the settings per person are unique for each team. If the same person is on both teams, having the settings be independent means you could allocate 60% of the person's capacity to team A and 40% on team B, since the person can't physically give 100% to both teams.

If you want to see the roll up of capacity in Team Father, there is a similar post at [Aggregating capacity for multiple teams in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829506/aggregating-capacity-for-multiple-teams-in-tfs).